# Is safe install MacPorts and keep Homebrew together? It for macOS El Capitan

Tags: install, homebrew, upgrade, software, macports

I have an old Mac, which uses `El Capitan`, impossible to do an upgrade, it is a MacBookPro bought in 2012 - it has 8GB of RAM and the disk is **not** `SSD`. Anyway I use this laptop in peace until some point.

I have kept installed `Homebrew`, it to not break something. And well, this software practically always works with the latest OS for Mac. I know that `MacPorts` is another recommended and good option - *correct me if it is not correct anymore* - to live in peace with this laptop

I have an issue about `SSH` as *client*, I can't connect anymore to some hosts. It seems because it is old - its version is `OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8`

The reason of this post:

**Question**:

- Is safe install `MacPorts` and keep `Homebrew` together?

My concern and goal is avoid get a "hang" event and conflicts, about the latter, arises an extra question:

**Extra Questions**

If is upgraded SSH as client (and other tools, such as MySQL etc)

- How does MacOS know which one to use? From `MacPorts` or `Homebrew`?

Comment: Why impossible to upgrade?

Comment: When I bought the laptop it came with `Mountain Lion` (if the name is correct) - when I did do the upgrade to the `El Capitan` - it because `Homebrew` in that time only supported that release - my Mac became slower and even the quality of sound was not good as the original - "Why impossible to upgrade?" - because I don't have the enough hardware ...

Comment: I asked because I have a 2011 iMac with an internal HDD and High Sierra on a JHFS+ formatted volume.  My Mac does not seem to run slow. While Safari is outdated, I an running the current version of Microsoft Edge. High Sierra also meets the minimum requirements for Chrome and FireFox. Your Mac can run at least Catalina, but I would not recommend Catalina (which requires APFS) unless  you upgrade to a internal SSD or add an external USB 3.0 (5 GHz) SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the polite feedback - now I understand your point - anyway I think is "safer" go through MacPorts.

Answer (score 3):

MacPorts supports El Capitan (in fact, back to Yosemite).

Homebrew does not.  Homebrew supports the same versions of macOS that Apple does.

Comment: Macports supports further back than yosemite. There is some support for tiger and fuller support for later osx

Comment: But is possible have both together in peace? I don't want uninstall Homebrew and break something in my Mac -

Comment: @ManuelJordan: I had nothing but trouble with "Homebrew" - for years. I'm sure some of it was my fault, but I've been very pleased with the reliability, stability and performance of MacPorts for many years now.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Homebrew is **unsupported** on the version of OS X you are running.  If it breaks, you get to keep all the pieces.  Homebrew will not help you.

Comment: @MarcWilson - yes, I know it is unsupported - that's why in my OP I wrote _"And well, this software practically always works with the latest OS for Mac"_ and it is the reason to use MacPorts - but I don't want uninstall Homebrew to avoid break something. So I want to know if I can install MacPorts and keep in peace Homebrew - therefore both installed in the same Mac

Comment: @ManuelJordan You may try but noone will help you. Your Homebrew apps will NOT have any security updates so you are running a risk - but then again nor does Apple. It depends on your use if you use gcc then there could be issues as old gcc hard codes /usr/local and so does not pick up Macports libraries before ones in /usr/local